# Segment Control Background Color

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is to possible to disable the blue color of segment control of selected index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

UIColor *newTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 251/255.0 green:175/255.0 blue:93/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    segmentedControl.tintColor = newTintColor;

UIColor *newSelectedTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0/255.0 green:175/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [[[segmentedControl subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
```