# UISegmentedButton setting tint color using pattern

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have the following code:

```
  UISegmentedControl * segmentedCtrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 35)];
    [segmentedCtrl setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"duck.png"]]];


 [segmentedCtrl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
```

And here's the duck image I am trying to use:

[image]

Anybody care to tell me why it's not working. I tried with any kind of image and it's not working. FYI Iam not trying to have a duck background in my segmented control. This is just to illustrate the point that setTint using the colorWithPatternImage doesn't work for any kind of image.

Comment: Have you tried using this color as a background color of some bigger view just to make sure that the problem really lies in `colorWithPatternImage:` part?

Comment: Ok, i downloaded your image. Download was of .jpeg type (XXWNo.jpg). Created a single view app and in viewDidLoad set viewControllers view background color with: `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XXWNo.jpg"]]];` the result was as expected a duck image on screen. Is your image really png (and firefox converts it to jpeg while downloading) or should you actually load it as a jpg image?

Comment: self.view works.. but not on segmentedController tintColor

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a 1px width image? The image you are using is too large for pattern creation

Answer (score 0):

`UISegmentedControl` (as all other UIKit controls, I think) doesn't support pattern colors as tint colors. The tint color is basically used to create a glossy gradient and that would have to be done very differently with an arbitrary pattern.

To customize the appearance of the background, use `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` and `setDividerImage:forLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:barMetrics:` instead (with appropriate images of course, patterns aren't a good fit for these).

Answer (score 0):

The tintColor on UISegmentedControl is only used as the basis to calculate the gradient used in the control. You can't very well have a gradient image, so it's just using part of it. It sounds like what you need is a custom subclass of UISegmentedControl.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
    [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up_button.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down_button.png"] atIndex:1 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

First take the RGB value of color by opening your image in Photochop , then use that values.

[segment-control-background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743404/segment-control-background-color)

Comment: How would this help him use a pattern (image) for background color?